# Error during wrapup: long vectors not supported yet: in glm() function

Tags: r, bigdata, out-of-memory, glm

I found several questions on **Stackoverflow** regarding this topic (some of them without any answer) but nothing related (so far) with this error in regression.

I'm, running a probit model in `r` with (I'm guessing) too many fixed effects (year and places):

```
myprobit <- glm(factor(Y) ~ factor(T) + factor(X1) + factor(X2) + factor(X3) +
                 factor(YEAR) + factor(PLACE),
                 family = binomial(link = "probit"),
                 data = DT)
```

The `PLACE` variable has about 1000 unique values and `YEAR` 8 values. The dataset `DT` has 13,099,225 obs and 79 columns.

The error I got is:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 59.3 Gb
Error during wrapup: long vectors not supported yet: ../include/Rinlinedfuns.h:519
```

The machine I'm using has 128 GB of RAM.

So, I don't know what I can do, without change the function. Does anyone know how to deal with this issue? Thanks!

Comment: You could start by removing all the extra columns in `DT` that you aren't using. But yes, my best guess is that you get the large assignment when it is building the model.matrix, because you have so many levels of your factors. This matrix will have 13 million rows and more than a 1000 columns. You could explore using a package like `biglm`.

Comment: Thanks @Axeman. I didn't know that package. Certainly, it's a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to close this question, I have to mention that the @Axeman's answer it is the only approach feasible for my problem. The whole issue is, there is not enough memory to manage such a huge design matrix.

Therefore, run a probit regression using the `biglm` package and `bigglm()` function is the only solution I found so far.

Nevertheless, I realize, due to how the `biglm` package works, taking iteratively chunks of the data, the use of `factor()` variables in the RHS it's problematic every time when factor level is not represented in the chunk. In other words, if a factor variable has 5 levels, but in the data chunk only 4 levels appear, I will have an error in the estimation.

There are several questions and comments about this on **Stackoverflow**.