# Using dplyr in order to change column value according to another df

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

Hello I have a **df1** :

```
scaf_name       coordinates value    
JZSA01000001.1  1   2
JZSA01000001.1  2   2
JZSA01000001.1  3   2
JZSA01000001.1  4   2
JZSA01000001.1  5   2
JZSA01000001.1  6   2
JZSA01000001.1  7   2
JZSA01000001.1  8   2
JZSA01000001.1  9   2
JZSA01000001.1  10  2
JZSA01000001.1  11  5
JZSA01000001.1  12  5
JZSA01000001.1  13  5
JZSA01000001.1  14  5
JZSA01000001.1  15  5
JZSA01000001.1  16  5
JZSA01000001.1  17  5
JZSA01000001.1  18  6
JZSA01000002.1  1   2
JZSA01000002.1  2   2
JZSA01000002.1  3   2
JZSA01000002.1  4   2
JZSA01000002.1  5   2
JZSA01000002.1  6   2
JZSA01000003.1  1   5
JZSA01000003.1  2   5
JZSA01000003.1  3   6
JZSA01000003.1  4   6
JZSA01000003.1  5   6
JZSA01000003.1  6   6
JZSA01000003.1  7   6
JZSA01000003.1  8   6
JZSA01000003.1  9   6
```

and another **df_interval**

```
scaffold          start     end
JZSA01000001.1_0  1         14
JZSA01000001.1_1  15        18
JZSA01000002.1    1         12
JZSA01000003.1_0  1         3
JZSA01000003.1_1  4         6
JZSA01000003.1_2  7         9
```

and I would like to change the `df1$scaf_name` according to the `df1$scaf_name$start` and `df1$scaf_name$end`

so for instance

every `df1$scaf_name` containing `df_interval$scaffold`  and where `df1$coordinates` os between `1-14` would be named `JZSA01000001.1_0`

Here I should get as output

```
scaf_name       coordinates value    
JZSA01000001.1_0    1   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    2   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    3   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    4   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    5   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    6   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    7   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    8   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    9   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    10  2
JZSA01000001.1_0    11  5
JZSA01000001.1_0    12  5
JZSA01000001.1_0    13  5
JZSA01000001.1_0    14  5
JZSA01000001.1_1    15  5
JZSA01000001.1_1    16  5
JZSA01000001.1_1    17  5
JZSA01000001.1_1    18  6
JZSA01000002.1      1   2
JZSA01000002.1      2   2
JZSA01000002.1      3   2
JZSA01000002.1      4   2
JZSA01000002.1      5   2
JZSA01000002.1      6   2
JZSA01000003.1_0    1   5
JZSA01000003.1_0    2   5
JZSA01000003.1_0    3   6
JZSA01000003.1_1    4   6
JZSA01000003.1_1    5   6
JZSA01000003.1_1    6   6
JZSA01000003.1_2    7   6
JZSA01000003.1_2    8   6
JZSA01000003.1_2    9   6
```

The df1 file is very huge, if someone have and idea to be the fastest possible it would be amazing.
Thank you

DATA

**df1**

```
structure(list(scaf_name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("JZSA01000001.1", 
"JZSA01000002.1", "JZSA01000003.1"), class = "factor"), coor = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L), dinates.value = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-33L))
```

**df_interval**

```
structure(list(scaffold = structure(1:6, .Label = c("JZSA01000001.1_0", 
"JZSA01000001.1_1", "JZSA01000002.1", "JZSA01000003.1_0", "JZSA01000003.1_1", 
"JZSA01000003.1_2"), class = "factor"), start = c(1L, 15L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 7L), end = c(14L, 18L, 12L, 3L, 6L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I got this solution :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df_interval, scaf_name := scaffold,
         on =  .(coordinates >= start, coordinates <= end)]
```

But for some `scaf_name` thery are removed from the output...

---

**Edit for Ronak**

here is the head of the equivalent (**df_interval** , here called **interval_tab** after) I used the code

setDT(interval_tab)[, scaf_name := sub("(?<=[0-9])_.", "", scaffold,perl = TRUE)]

```
> head(interval_tab)
       scaffold start   end  scaf_name
1:   KQ759765.1     1  1417 KQ759765.1
2:   KQ759766.1     1  1389 KQ759766.1
3: KQ759767.1_0     1 23930 KQ759767.1
4: KQ759767.1_1 23931 83220 KQ759767.1
5: KQ759767.1_2 83221 92117 KQ759767.1
6: KQ759767.1_3 92118 92679 KQ759767.1
```

and here is the head of the equivalent **df1** (here called **tab**)

```
> head(tab)
           V1 V2 V3
1: KQ759765.1  1  0
2: KQ759765.1  2  0
3: KQ759765.1  3  0
4: KQ759765.1  4  0
5: KQ759765.1  5  0
6: KQ759765.1  6  0
```

then I used your code :

```
> setDT(tab)[interval_tab, scaf_name := scaffold,on =  .(scaf_name, V2 >= start, V2 <= end)]
```

and got the error message

```
Error in colnamesInt(x, names(on), check_dups = FALSE) : 
  argument specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[1]='scaf_name'
```

Comment: Can you specifiy "every df1$scaf_name containing df_interval$scaffold and where df1$coordinates os between 1-14 would be named JZSA01000001.1_0"? Do you mean when every scaffold without the before the underscore matches with scaf_name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a key which is common between  `df_interval` and `df1`. For that you can create a new column to remove everything after an underscore in `scaffold` column and then do the join.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_interval)[, scaf_name := sub('_.*', '', scaffold)]

setDT(df1)[df_interval, scaf_name := scaffold,on =  
                       .(scaf_name, coor >= start, coor <= end)]
```

This returns :

```
#           scaf_name coor dinates.value
# 1: JZSA01000001.1_0    1             2
# 2: JZSA01000001.1_0    2             2
# 3: JZSA01000001.1_0    3             2
# 4: JZSA01000001.1_0    4             2
# 5: JZSA01000001.1_0    5             2
# 6: JZSA01000001.1_0    6             2
# 7: JZSA01000001.1_0    7             2
# 8: JZSA01000001.1_0    8             2
# 9: JZSA01000001.1_0    9             2
#10: JZSA01000001.1_0   10             2
#11: JZSA01000001.1_0   11             5
#12: JZSA01000001.1_0   12             5
#13: JZSA01000001.1_0   13             5
#14: JZSA01000001.1_0   14             5
#15: JZSA01000001.1_1   15             5
#16: JZSA01000001.1_1   16             5
#17: JZSA01000001.1_1   17             5
#18: JZSA01000001.1_1   18             6
#19:   JZSA01000002.1    1             2
#20:   JZSA01000002.1    2             2
#21:   JZSA01000002.1    3             2
#22:   JZSA01000002.1    4             2
#23:   JZSA01000002.1    5             2
#24:   JZSA01000002.1    6             2
#25: JZSA01000003.1_0    1             5
#26: JZSA01000003.1_0    2             5
#27: JZSA01000003.1_0    3             6
#28: JZSA01000003.1_1    4             6
#29: JZSA01000003.1_1    5             6
#30: JZSA01000003.1_1    6             6
#31: JZSA01000003.1_2    7             6
#32: JZSA01000003.1_2    8             6
#33: JZSA01000003.1_2    9             6
#           scaf_name coor dinates.value
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, I tried but I got the message : ``` Error in colnamesInt(i, unname(on), check_dups = FALSE) : 
  argument specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[1]='scaf_name' ``` do you have an idea @Ronak ?

Comment: Are you testing this on the data that you have shared or some other data? The regex may differ on different data. The key here is column name in `df1` and `df_interval` should match.

Comment: Yes I'm using it on other biger data now, by they should match you mean all the value should match ?

Comment: Notice your 1st `df1` value , it is `JZSA01000001.1`, now check your first `df_interval` value it is `JZSA01000001.1_0`. We need to match them but we cannot directly do that. In my answer I use `sub` in first line `setDT(df_interval)[, scaf_name := sub('_.*', '', scaffold)]` to remove everything after underscore so that `JZSA01000001.1_0` becomes `JZSA01000001.1` which will match the value in `df1`. you need to do the same thing in your real dataset now so that column values are same and we can join them.

Comment: yes I done that but I used : ```setDT(interval_tab)[, scaf_name := sub("(?<=[0-9])_.", "", scaffold,perl = TRUE)]```since I needed to remove everything after a ```Number_```

Comment: So is `scaf_name` matching in both the dataframe? Can you check manually couple of them. From the error message that you received `argument specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[1]='scaf_name'` it seems one of the dataframe does not have column named `scaf_name`. Is it called something else? Can you confirm?

Comment: Ho yes sorry in my exemple here the code would be : ```setDT(df_interval)[, scaf_name := sub("(?<=[0-9])_.", '', scaffold)] ``` in fact the columns names are different from the exemple and my real data, but the column does really exist. @Ronak I edited my post in order to show you the head of my data

Comment: Maybe ```scaf_name```not all match with ```V1```but how can I check that (I guess it is only for couple of themp an not so much, and there is a huge number of unique values actually

Comment: You don't have `scaf_name` in `tab` so you have to mention the column that you are joining with. Try `setDT(tab)[interval_tab, scaf_name := scaffold,on =  .(V1 = scaf_name, V2 >= start, V2 <= end)]`

Answer (score 0):

This could work, you just have to delete the old column if you want:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 = structure(list(scaf_name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("JZSA01000001.1", 
                                                                                                     "JZSA01000002.1", "JZSA01000003.1"), class = "factor"), coor = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                      2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
                                                                                                                                                                      16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
                                                                                                                                                                      7L, 8L, 9L), dinates.value = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               -33L))
df_interval = structure(list(scaffold = structure(1:6, .Label = c("JZSA01000001.1_0", 
                                                                  "JZSA01000001.1_1", "JZSA01000002.1", "JZSA01000003.1_0", "JZSA01000003.1_1", 
                                                                  "JZSA01000003.1_2"), class = "factor"), start = c(1L, 15L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                    1L, 4L, 7L), end = c(14L, 18L, 12L, 3L, 6L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                          -6L))
df_t = df1 %>%
  inner_join(df_interval, by = c("scaf_name" = "scaffold")) %>%
  mutate(newcol = case_when(coor>= 1 & coor <= 14 ~ "JZSA01000001.1_0 ")) %>%
  select(c("newcol", "coor", "dinates.value"))
```

**EDIT**
Now the old valuesa are replaced. I changed from inner to left join

```
df_t = df1 %>%
  left_join(df_interval, by = c("scaf_name" = "scaffold")) %>%
  mutate(scaf_name = replace(scaf_name, coor >= 1 &
                               coor <= 14 &
                               !is.na(end), "JZSA01000001.1_0")) %>% 
  select(c("scaf_name", "coor", "dinates.value"))
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok now I think I got it. Assuming the underscore split is ok, this works and looks like your solution:

```
df_interval$shorti = do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df_interval$scaffold), "_"))[,1]
df_t = df1 %>%
  left_join(df_interval, by = c("scaf_name" = "shorti")) %>%
  filter(coor >= start & coor <= end) %>%
  mutate(scaf_name = ifelse(coor >= start &
                              coor <= end, as.character(scaffold), scaf_name)) %>%
  select(c("scaf_name", "coor", "dinates.value"))
```

Comment: Hello, thank you but I do not understand why you add this part : ```case_when(coor>= 1 & coor <= 14 ~ "JZSA01000001.1_0 "))```the result only give me the output for ```JZSA01000001.1```then and not for all sequences... @sequoia

Comment: well not exaclty, ```JZSA01000002.1```has been removed I do not know why, maybe you could see the expected output I wrote in the post ?

Comment: Hello, I used another dataframe and got the error :  ```Error in vec_slice(x_out, x_slicer) : 
  long vectors not supported yet: ../../src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h:519```do you have an idea of was is going on? @sequoia

Comment: Is it important anymore? Since you marked the other answer as helpful. But it just means that your matrix/vector is too big. And how suggested here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/60419930/6946122), you can use the 
`biglm` package